# C++ ostream formatting

Tags: c++, formatting, ostream

I want to get a C++ class `Xyz` such that the following:

```
Xyz mything("/tmp/x1");

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    mything << "Hello world";
}
```

causes a file "/tmp/x1" to be created, and the following

> 2013-12-04 12:01 :: Hello world

to be written to it.

The first issue I have is that `ostream` has many specialised methods for each type that may follow the `<<`.  The second is that if I have

```
cout << "hello" << "world";
```

and

```
cout << "hello";
```

then the implementation for `operator <<` called for `"hello"` needs to know whether anything follows it in the statement (how do I effectively do an `if(last_in_line_of_<<)` type construct?).
The standard `cout` does this by having objects like `endl`.

Basically I want to create a global log object with a single line, once the class has been defined, and to write to it with `ostream` operations such that the string that, say, `cout` would get would be wrapped in a larger string.

I've ended up looking at this way of doing it since the `varargs` way is painful and many people seem to recommend against it.

In scripting languages like Python and Ruby, objects have a `str` or `to_s` method (or equivalent) and `print` and `format` call these to format them, so that `"hello {} world".format(x)` formats one parameter, and `"hello {} world".format(" ".join(x))` joins a list, after formatting to strings, with spaces and then sticks that into the resulting string.

I'm wondering what the right C++ way is to do this.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::ofstream` and/or `std::stringstream`?

Comment: The only reason `cout << x << y` works is that `<<` returns a reference to the stream. The implementation knows nothing about if another expression follows `cout << x`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You could return a temporary from `my_class << x` that does some stream insertion operation in its dtor. (And is there a reason to prefer a blockquote `>` over a preformatted block `<pre>`?)

Comment: @DyP The blockquote has a larger border and it supports inline code blocks.

Comment: I'm not completely understanding what you want done here. Can you summarize?

Answer (score 1):

Instad to giving to `Xyz` a stream behavior, make it a manipulator and use normal streams facilities:

A function prototyped as

```
std::ostream& logtime(std::ostream& s)
{
   /* write date and time to s */
   return s;
}
```

can be used as

```
std::cout << logtime << "text and other things" << std::endl;
```

if std::cout is replaced by whatever other *ostream* (like a `outfile` variable of type `std::filestream`) you get exactly that effect, but using a manipulator that can work with whatever type of output stream (non necessarily a file)

```
std::ofstream outfile("file");
outfile << logtime << "text and whatever else" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to **format your output**, see [iomanip](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/) in the [Standard C++ Library reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) at cplusplus.com.

For example:

- **setfill** -- Set fill character
- **setprecision** -- Set decimal precision
- **setw** -- Set field width